# Can I stop settings in vimrc from being overwritten by plugins?

Tags: php, plugins, vim

This question follows on from [this vim search question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299114/can-i-search-for-php-class-members-and-methods-with-vim-star-search)

I have a setting in my .vimrc which excludes $ as a valid part of a word:

```
set iskeyword-=$
```

This works fine for most files but isn't working in PHP. I assume it is being overwritten by a php plugin, but since plugins are loaded after .vimrc I can't work out how to overwrite this setting. I'd prefer not to have to type

```
:set isk-=$
```

every time I load a PHP file.

Any suggestions?

( Ubuntu 8.04 / Vim 7.1.138 if it matters )

**Summary**

Two excellent answers, thank you!

I went with [tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak)'s because it was less effort, and added the following to my ~/.vimrc

```
autocmd FileType php setlocal isk-=$
```

but thanks also to [Luc Hermitte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305574/can-i-stop-settings-in-vimrc-from-being-overwritten-by-plugins#305820). Putting the settings in a ~/vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim file also worked.

*:help autocmd* and *:help after-directory* both helped too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would probably just add `set isk-=$` to my syntax highlighting auto command in `$VIMRUNTIME\filetype.vim`. Don't know if it is the nicest way to do it, though.

Thinking about it... I think it would be enough to have an appropriate autocommand in your `vimrc`.

```
au   FileType php    set isk-=$
```

This executes after the FileType has been set. Auto commands are executed in the order they are given, so when you put it late in your `vimrc` it will execute last for PHP files.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, I'll try that. Being lazy I was really hoping for something I wouldn't have to redo with every update of Vim though.

Comment: @Ken: you can do his suggestion in your own vim directory. never mess with the system's files

Answer (score 8):

Add a {rtp}/after/ftplugin/php.vim that contains the `:setlocal isk-=$`

Otherwise, you will have to track where it has been changed last with `:verbose set isk`, or by playing with `:scriptnames`

Answer (score -2):

Make a copy of your .vimrc, e.g. .vimrc.ref

Make the copy in another directory.

Then find out why the plugin authors really need to just clobber your .vimrc without:

1. letting you know that they're clobbering it, and
2. saving a copy of your .vimrc file so you can easily roll back.

Edit: And let http://www.vim.org/ know about those who would reach under your covers without letting you know!

Comment: I don't think the plugin is altering his vimrc, I think he means that the plugin is changing the value of iskeyword, and adding back this character that he removed. When not editing PHP, iskeyword setting is fine.

Comment: rjray's interpretation is correct - the .vimrc isn't being altered, but the values are being changed by a plugin. Maybe overwritten is the wrong word to have used. Thank you for your contribution anyway!